# How big of a number can you store in double and float in c?

Tags: c, floating-point, sizeof

I am trying to figure out exactly how big number I can use as floating point number and `double`. But it does not store the way I expected except integer value. `double` should hold 8 bytes of information which is enough to hold variable a, but it does not hold it right. It shows `1234567890123456768` in which last 2 digits are different. And when I stored `214783648` or any digit in the last digit in float variable `b`, it shows the same value `214783648`. which is supposed to be the limit. So what's going on?

```
double a;
float b;
int c;
a = 1234567890123456789;
b = 2147483648;
c = 2147483647;
printf("Bytes of double: %d\n", sizeof(double));
printf("Bytes of integer: %d\n", sizeof(int));
printf("Bytes of float: %d\n", sizeof(float));

printf("\n");

printf("You can count up to %.0f in 4 bytes\n", pow(2,32));
printf("You can count up to %.0f with + or - sign in 4 bytes\n", pow(2,31));
printf("You can count up to %.0f in 4 bytes\n", pow(2,64));
printf("You can count up to %.0f with + or - sign in in 8 bytes\n", pow(2,63));

printf("\n");

printf("double number: %.0f\n", a);
printf("floating point: %.0f\n", b);
printf("integer: %d\n", c);

return 0;
```

Comment: use `%zu` to print the o/p of `sizeof`

Comment: All defined in header file `limits.h`.

Comment: You can store INFINITY! =)

Answer (score 13):

The answer to the question of what is the largest (finite) number that can be stored in a floating point type would be `FLT_MAX` or `DBL_MAX` for `float` and `double`, respectively.

However, that doesn't mean that the type can precisely represent every smaller number or integer (in fact, not even close).

First you need to understand that not all bits of a floating point number are “equal”. A floating point number has an *exponent* (8 bits in IEEE-754 standard `float`, 11 bits in `double`), and a *mantissa* (23 and 52 bits in `float`, and `double` respectively). The number is obtained by multiplying the mantissa (which has an implied leading 1-bit and binary point) by 2<sup>exponent</sup> (after normalizing the exponent; its binary value is not used directly). There is also a separate sign bit, so the following applies to negative numbers as well.

As the exponent changes, the distance between consecutive values of the mantissa changes as well, i.e., the greater the exponent, *the further apart* consecutive representable values of the floating point number are. Thus you may be able to store one number of a given magnitude precisely, but not the “next” number. One should also remember that some seemingly simple fractions can not be represented precisely with any number of binary digits (e.g., `1/10`, one tenth, is an infinitely repeating sequence in binary, like `1/3`, one third, is in decimal).

When it comes to integers, you can precisely represent every integer up to 2<sup>mantissa_bits + 1</sup> magnitude. Thus an IEEE-754 `float` can represent all integers up to 2<sup>24</sup> and a `double` up to 2<sup>53</sup> (in the last half of these ranges the consecutive floating point values are exactly one integer apart, since the entire mantissa is used for the integer part only). There are individual larger integers that can be represented, but they are spaced more than one integer apart, i.e., you can represent *some* integers greater than 2<sup>mantissa_bits + 1</sup> but *every* integer only up to that magnitude.

For example:

```
float f = powf(2.0f, 24.0f);
float f1 = f + 1.0f, f2 = f1 + 2.0f;
double d = pow(2.0, 53.0);
double d1 = d + 1.0, d2 = d + 2.0;
(void) printf("2**24 float = %.0f, +1 = %.0f, +2 = %.0f\n", f, f1, f2);
(void) printf("2**53 double = %.0f, +1 = %.0f, +2 = %.0f\n", d, d1, d2);
```

Outputs:

```
2**24 float = 16777216, +1 = 16777216, +2 = 16777218
2**53 double = 9007199254740992, +1 = 9007199254740992, +2 = 9007199254740994
```

As you can see, adding `1` to 2<sup>mantissa_bits + 1</sup> makes no difference since the result is not representable, but adding `2` does produce the correct answer (as it happens, at this magnitude the representable numbers are two integers apart since the multiplier has doubled).

TL;DR An IEE-754 `float` can precisely represent all integers up to 2<sup>24</sup> and `double` up to 2<sup>53</sup>, but only some integers of greater magnitude (the spacing of representable values depends on the magnitude).

Comment: Great answer. Since it's already long anyway, I would mention somewhere that it's even more counter-intuitive when it comes to fractional numbers, since even a seemingly simple number such as 0.4 is only simple when viewed in decimal, and is not simple (and cannot be represented exactly) in binary.

Comment: A simplified mental model for this would be to imagine grid paper where you have space to write a given number of digits, but you can place the point between any of those digits. That is, the magnitude of the number changes by the placement of the point, but you still have the same number of digits for precision. (The concept of having a movable, or floating, point is what gives floating point numbers their name.)

Answer (score 7):

`sizeof(double)` is `8`, true, but `double` needs some bits to store the *exponent* part as well.

Assuming IEEE-754 is used, `double` can represent integers at most  2<sup>53</sup> precisely, which is less than `1234567890123456789`.

See also [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Answer (score 3):

You can use constants to know what are the limits :

```
FLT_MAX
DBL_MAX
LDBL_MAX
```

[From CPP reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)

Comment: Remember that these are platform, OS, compiler, and compile option dependent.

Comment: This is not the answer. `1234567890123456789` is much less than `DBL_MAX`, which is usually `1E+37`. The real problem in this question is not the maximum number that `double` can store, but how big an integer that `double` can store **precisely**.

Comment: @YuHao: DBL_MAX is "usually **`1E+37`**"? Typo? IIRC, it is something around `1E307`.

Comment: @Olaf  **Correction** to my earlier comment: The *minimum* acceptable value for `DBL_MAX` is `1E+37`. It's usually much bigger, something like `1.79769e+308`.

Comment: @YuHao    E+308? I am confused. I was taught that C is a language which can't hold really big numbers. And we were taught to store huge numbers in arrays. Can you please explain?

Comment: @KaranSingh You were taught correctly, but floating-point complicates things. If you needed more digits/significant figures at that scale you wouldn't be able to do it. Although e+308 is large, the number of figures is only 6 in this example! (24 ish in reality for a double). Whether this counts as "storing a really big number" is a matter of philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the actual limits of the standard POD-types by printing the limits stored in the 'limits.h' header file (for C++ the equivalent is  'std::numeric_limits' identifier as shown here:
[enter link description here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/))

Due to the fact that the hardware doesn't work with floating types respectively cannot represent floating types by hardware in reality, the hardware uses the bit-length of your hardware to represent a floating type. Since you don't have an infinit length for floating types, you can only show/present a double variable for a specific precision. Most of the hardware uses for the floating type presentation the IEEE-754 standard.

To get more precision you could try 'long double' (dependend on the hardware this could be of quadruple-precision than double), AVX,SSE registers, big-num libraries or you coudl do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` an object only reports the memory space it occupies. It does not show the valid *range*. It would be well possible to have an `unsigned int` with e.g. 2**16 (65536) possible value occupy 32 bits im memory.

For [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) objects, it is more difficult. They consist of (simplified) two fields: an integer mantissa and an exponent (see details in the linked article). Both with a fixed width.

As the mantissa only has a limited range, trailing bits are truncated or rounded and the exponent is corrected, if required. This is one reason one should never use floating point types to store precise values like currency.

In decimal (note: computers use binary representation) with 4 digit mantissa:

```
1000 --> 1.000e3
12345678 --> 1.234e7
```

The paramters for your implementation are defined in `float.h` similar to `limits.h` which provides parameters for integers.

Answer (score -2):

On Linux, `#include <values.h>`

On Windows,`#include <float.h>`

There is a fairly comprehensive list of defines